# BIRT Report Selection Page

Tags: jsp, birt

I've set up a BIRT report server and have developed several reports for it.  The reports work and all, but I haven't figured out a way to simply display a list of reports available so that a user can select one to run.

Right now, I've gotta give people a direct link to each report, but as more get developed, that'll become less and less tenable.  I see `index.html`, which just links over to BIRT's sample report.  I feel like that page should simply list all reports.

Does this functionality already exist, or must I create it?  If it's in my hands, have others solved this already, and are there solutions that I can reference/adopt?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a BIRT report to generate the list of links? This report, let's call it "index.rptdesign", could use a Scripted Data Set generated from the directory listing. Furthermore, it could use the DE API to read the properties of the individual reports (comments, title, author, you name it...).

Comment: i figured i'd have to do something like that.  i'll experiment with your idea, and ... report ...back!